# CK Editor Content Cropping while display

Tags: php, ckeditor, substring

We are using a CKEditor to add content to a specific field(for example description). We have a functionality where we display this content entered with a certain character limit(for example mini description which must be 200 characters long) permitted within a container. Since the content of the ckeditor is HTML, if we apply any server side substring function, the html of the editor content will be broken. Is there any solution to set the number of characters shown based on text alone while retaining the necessary html required for it? In simple words no matter how big the editor content is we need the first 200 text characters to be displayed. Please note setting a limit while adding data is not an option due to a different reason. Having a container with a fixed height to hide the rest of the content also wont serve the purpose.  A php or a Javascript solution will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

For clarity, this is what we are doing. We are entering overview about a course which is entered via a CKEditor along with many other fields like title, category etc. Now we have a list of courses page where all the courses are shown. In this list we have to show a small portion of the overview(say first 200 characters). We cannot show the entire overview because it will be lengthy. I want to create a substring of the overview which picks only the first 200 characters.

Comment: Could you re-read your question and maybe clarify it a little? I at least am having a hard time understanding the requirement. Do you want a CKEditor that hides any text and elements after 200 chars? Really? Or do you want to limit the amount of visible characters a user can input to 200 - meaning that further data is just truncated? Or do you want to limit the amount of data shown in a view? Neway, you will still need to use some kind of serverside validation if this is a critical (or public :p) app because at least a JS solution sounds like it can quite easily be bypassed by a skilled user.

Comment: @Nenotlep I want to limit the data shown in a view. I have edited the question too.

Comment: Now it's more clear. This is a very very difficult task. When the content is this complex I've seen this solved time and time again with two separate input fields for data. One plain old textbox for the short text / ingress and one wysiwyg for the extended content. Then it's up to the user to write the 200 char limited short text. I highly recommend this option :). A straight up limiter can be done with JS, but it will be un ugly thing. You sure want to go down that path? Even a CSS option would be nicer I'd guess. :)

Comment: @Nenotlep Even I always believed in adding a separate field for mini description. But I was just wondering if there was a way out so as to avoid the redundant field. Thanks though! Will either choose the CSS or the additional field approach.